# Guessing game range

Tags: java

I am done with my class assignment except one thing that could not figure it out yet.
How can i make the program to only allow numbers in the range of 1 to 100? If user type a number which less than 1 or higher than 100, it should tell user that the number out of range.

I setup a random class and a while loop which takes the input and tells user the number is too high or low. If the number is correct, displays you win massage. Everything works but only the range part. 
 import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class GuessingGame {

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

    Random generator = new Random(); 
    int numberToGuess = 1 + generator.nextInt(100);
    int numberOfTries = 0;

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    int guess;
    boolean win = false;


    System.out.println("You have 10 tries to guess a number between 1 and 100");

    while(!win && numberOfTries < 10)
    {
    System.out.println("Guess a number: ");
    guess = input.nextInt();

    if (guess < 1 || guess > 100)
    {
    System.out.println("Guess is out of range!");
    continue; 
    }


    if (guess == numberToGuess) 
    {
        win=true;
    }

    else if (guess < numberToGuess)
            {
            System.out.println("Your guess is too low");
            }
    else if (guess > numberToGuess)
            {
            System.out.println("Your guess is too high");
            }

    }

    System.out.println("You win!");
    System.out.println("The number was " + numberToGuess);
    System.out.println("It took you " + numberOfTries + " tries." );


}
```

}
- I added rest of the codes -

But if i type numbers like  -1 or 101, the program says the number too high or the number too low, ignores the out of range statement. Cant figure it out why. 
Could you please help me?
Thank you

Comment: are you missing a  } at the end of "break;" ?

Comment: Side note: It's better to write `!win` instead of `win == false`.

Comment: This is not your real code. There is no `If` in Java. Please post something more loyal to your real code.

Comment: Also I hope `If` is a typo in the question, should be `if`.

Comment: "if i type numbers like -1 [...] the program says [...] the number too low"... Isn't that what you want?

Comment: @LenaBru Sorry i missed type here, but even with closed bracket, it still ignored the "out of range" statement.

Comment: @ReutSharabani Thank you for the notification but it is all about missed typing the code. I did not copy/paste the code.

Comment: @user3189142 no i want the program only allow the number between 1 to 100, if not should display "out of range" message. :(

Answer (score 1):

I added some improvements to your code:

`numberOfTries++` after checking the valid range, because you need to increase this number, otherwise the loop will not end after 10 guesses.

`break` when player wins, because you don't want the loop to continue in that case.

And after the loop you need to check if the player won or not. It is also possible that he guessed 10 times without winning.

I think now it should work as expected.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random generator = new Random(); 
    int numberToGuess = 1 + generator.nextInt(100);
    int numberOfTries = 0;

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    int guess;
    boolean win = false;

    System.out.println("You have 10 tries to guess a number between 1 and 100");

    while(!win && numberOfTries < 10)
    {
        System.out.println("Guess a number: ");
        guess = input.nextInt();

        if (guess < 1 || guess > 100)
        {
            System.out.println("Guess is out of range!");
            continue; 
        }

        // increase numberOfTries by 1 because player made another valid guess
        numberOfTries++;

        if (guess == numberToGuess) 
        {
            win=true;
            // exit the while loop because player won
            break;
        }

        if (guess < numberToGuess)
        {
            System.out.println("Your guess is too low");
        }
        else 
        {
            // guess must be > numberToGuess here
            System.out.println("Your guess is too high");
        }
    }

    if(win)
    {
        System.out.println("You win!");
        System.out.println("The number was " + numberToGuess);
        System.out.println("It took you " + numberOfTries + " tries." );
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Sorry, you didn't win.");
        System.out.println("The right number was " + numberToGuess);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sky, you are awesome! Thank you very much. It is finally giving "out of range" error. I also modified your code to show numberOfTries in every guess (exp: guess number 1:, guess number 2:, ... so and so forth), i am done with my assignment. Thanks a lot again Sky :)

Comment: You are welcome @ebyrock. Hint for next time: show more of your code. With the part you showed in your initial question, it was impossible to guess what the problem was.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `break` will make the program exit the `while` loop, without giving any chance to input a number again. Use `continue` instead.

Comment: No, it does not exits the program instead display message like the number too high or low. So `break:` acts like `continue;`. I wish it makes the program exit so i can know where is the problem. :(

Comment: Well it's hard to know what really happens in that program, seen that @ebyrock did not post the whole code but just part of it. If a number less than 1 or greater than 100 is entered, `break` will end the `while` loop. As Michał Szydłowski correctly stated, `continue` would be the right choice here, because you want the user to be able to try and guess again. Also, `numberOfTries++` should be written after checking if the number is within the desired range, otherwise you count invalid guesses, too.

Comment: @Sky i added rest of the codes. Doesn't matter if i use `continue;` , still getting same result. Here is my output:

`run:
You have 10 tries to guess a number between 1 and 100
Guess number 1: 120
Your guess is too high
Guess number 1: `

Comment: @epyrock Thank you. I took a look and wrote an answer with some fixes in your code. Please try that out. And take care to run the right code. You wrote your output states `Guess number 1:` which the code you've published here would not print out. Just to make sure you are actually running the code you think you are running.

Answer (score 0):

The `break` keyword is used to exit the nearest loop body, because that is your while loop, using it will end your number guessing game. You want to use the `continue` keyword, which will start the next iteration of the loop immediately:

```
while(!win && numberOfGuesses < 10)
{
    System.out.println("Guess a number: ");
    guess = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());

    if (guess < 1 || guess > 100)
    {
        System.out.println("Guess is out of range!");
        continue; //Use this instead of break
    }

    //Rest of your code
}
```

Comment: Using continue did not change the result. I also added rest of the codes.